# How does Aspose.Cells read/create MS Excel file

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-mvc, aspose-cells

Does it have a dependency on something like a COM interface or OleDb that it installs as a redistributable package or does it read [Excel Binary File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313154%28v=office.14%29.aspx) directly?

Just want to know how it works before I install it on my servers..

Comment: Do the app have any COM references?  Pretty sure Aspose .NET is .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspose.Cells for .NET reads and writes the Excel file directly. It does not have any dependency on any other COM component.

The only requirement is the .NET Framework.

I work as a Developer Evangelist for Aspose.